# Single Sign-On with Web- and Desktop-Client application

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, keycloak

My team is in the process of modernizing a legacy application. Part of that is replacing the old desktop-client with a new web-client. For the foreseeable future, both clients will exist in parallel while we migrate more and more features from old to new. Another part of this effort is to replace our hand-rolled authentication & authorization mechanism with a OAuth solution with Keycloak.

What we want to do now is the following:

Our newest feature will exist only in the web-client. To use it from the desktop-client, a click on the corresponding button will simply open the system's browser with a specific URL.

That's already somewhat inconvenient and we want to minimize any further inconvenience for the user. The user has already logged in when the desktop-client started. We prefer not to ask the user to log in again in the web-client, especially because they will likely open and close this browser window multiple times over the day instead of leaving it open all the time (although we expect the behaviour to change over time when more and more old features migrate over). Ideally the user would also stay logged in if they choose to open the browser manually afterwards.

How can we achieve this? Our current idea is as follows:

1. When the user logs in with the desktop client, the server uses the credentials to perform *both* the old login as well as obtain access&refresh tokens from Keycloak.
2. The server refreshes the tokens periodically.
3. All old functionality accessed from the desktop-client will use the old mechanism, all the new functionality will use access tokens.
4. When the user clicks the new button, a nonce is generated on the server, communicated to the desktop client which appends it to the browser window's URL. The browser exchanges the nonce for the access&refresh tokens.

This workflow only partially solves the problem. Disadvantages:

- This only works if both the server and the web-client can refresh their access tokens independently of each other. If the refresh-token is one-time-use (which we would like for increased security) this is not possible. The web-client needs to refresh because the new feature may take some time to click through, longer than a single access token is valid. The server needs to refresh its set of tokens to be ready for when the user clicks on the button again.
- The server would use password_grant in this scenario which does not establish a session on the Keycloak server. Therefore no session cookies can be set in the browser and the user would be forced to login again if they open the browser manually.

I'm sure we're not the first to have this kind of problem. How do other companies solve it? I know that one way is to switch the order and use the browser for the desktop-client's login as well. But that won't work in our case, because the server still requires the user's credentials for the old authorization functionality. While we could switch over authentication to OAuth right now, authorization is complicated and will take some time until we're ready to switch.

If it helps: Both server and desktop-client are written in Java. The web-client uses Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference - This is what we did in the end: We use Keycloak for OAuth and Keycloak supports [direct naked impersonation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#direct-naked-impersonation) which we use now.

The "Token Exchange" feature is activated and our backend is set up to have the "impersonation" permission in Keycloak.

Then the flow of events is as follows:

1. The user logs into the old client as usual.
2. When the user klicks on the button, first we request a one-time-use-token with an very short lifetime from the backend (a random UUID that's valid for something like 5s in this case).
3. The client opens the local browser and supplies the one-time-use-token via query parameter.
4. The web-frontend detects the query parameter and sends another request to the backend. The token serves as a temporary authentication.
5. The backend validates the token and performs direct naked impersonation for the user that originally created the token.
6. The resulting set of access & refresh tokens is sent to the web-frontend which uses it as it would have used a token set directly from keycloak (because this *is* a token set directly from keycloak). The web-frontend proceeds to use the rest of the API as usual.

Advantages:

- There is no need for the backend to keep access/refresh tokens. It does not need to store passwords for users to perform password_grant logins on their behalf.
- single-use refresh tokens are no problem now.
- There is no keycloak session associated with this token set. So single-sign on with other applications will not work. Another, separately started browser window using the web-frontend will still ask for authentication. In the end we decided that it's better this way, because this does not allow another user on the same PC (e.g. an employee working the following shift) to use the session of the previous user.

Disadvantage:

- Keycloak's "Token Exchange" feature that is necessary for this is still in experimental status. There is hope that something very similar will be standardised in the future and Keycloak will implement the standard with a sufficiently similar HTTP request.